# Apportable - clicking back on navigation bar shows a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, apportable

Let's say I have two UIViewControllers: Home and Detail.
When a button is pressed in Home, I want to push Detail view

```
- (IBAction) proceed
{
    DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    controller.title = @"Details..";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

On iOS, when Detail view is pushed, if I click on the back button on navigation bar I can definitely goes back to home view.

On Android, when Detail view is pushed, if I click on the 'home' title on the top left of the navigation bar, I will go back to a black screen.

Is simple UINavigation working in Apportable already?

Take note that both xib are 4.6 compatible.